# Connection timed out issue at server , but code working fine at localhost

Tags: curl, drupal-7, timeout

I call some api using drupal_http_request(). At localhost it is working fine. 
but at server I got Connection timed out error where error code -110.

I set

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 120);
$conf['http_request_timeout'] = 120;
```

at my settings.php. But not working at server.

Error :

```
stdClass Object ( [code] => -110 [error] => Connection timed out )
```

Comment: Check server configuration , php.ini , nginx or apache , etc..

Comment: My server has some PROXY , I pass proxy when calling API. It is working fine now.